# how to reload only navbar in angularjs because I have to change to login to logout anchor in it

Tags: angularjs

How to reload only navbar to change the login anchor to logout with the help of session.

1. [before login it should be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFw4y.jpg)
2. [after login it should change with help of session](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyYWb.jpg)

*code of navbar*

```
    <body>
     <?php

    session_start();
    ?>
             <div class="container-fluid" style="margin-left: 0px ">
            <img  src="Images/pro_1.JPG" class="img-responsive" style="width:90%; height:170px;"  />     
         </div>

            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse my-navbar"  style="border-bottom: thin solid red; width:100%;  border-width:5px;">
        <div class="container-fluid" >
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header" ng-app="Demo" ng-hide="myVar">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/" style="font-size: 15px; font-weight: 900; ">HOME</a>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/search" style="font-size: 15px; font-weight: 900; ">SEARCH DONORS</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"  ng-controller="loginCtrl" >
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="ul1">
            <li style="font-size: 15px; font-weight: 900; "><a href="#/bloodtips">BLOOD TIPS</a>
            </li>
            <li style="font-size: 15px; font-weight: 900; "><a href="#/aboutus">ABOUT US</a>
            </li>
         </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

    <!--      <li style="font-size: 15px; font-weight: 900; "><a href="#/login" ng-show="!isUserLoggedIn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> LOGIN</a></li>
          <li style="font-size: 15px; font-weight: 900; "><a href="#/login" ng-show="isUserLoggedIn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> LOGOUT</a></li>-->
          <?php 
          if(@$_SESSION['id']!="")
                {?>
                <div class="mainmenu pull-left">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav collapse navbar-collapse">
                        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#/dashboard"><?php echo @$_SESSION['id']; ?>
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                <ul role="menu" class="sub-menu">
                <li><a style="background: transparent" href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </li> 
                </ul>
                </div>

            <?php   }
                    else
                    {   ?>
                 <li style="font-size: 15px; font-weight: 900; " ><a href="#/register"  ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> REGISTER AS DONAR</a></li>          
              <li><a href="#/login"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Login</a></li>
                    <?php   }   ?>
        </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

    </nav>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no reload of a specific part in AngularJS.

What you have to do is 2 templates; one for logged user and one for not logged.

Your function responsible for authentication will set a variable :
 - as true for authenticated user
 - as false for logout

Within your html; you will have a `ng-if="autenticationVariable=== true"` test to check that

Comment: i didnt understand ,please can you explain me with an example i am new to angularjs